# Hilbert Space and Projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> If $M$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H$ and $x$ $\in$ $H$, prove that:
>   $$\underset{y \in M}{\min} ||x-y|| =\max\{|\langle x,z\rangle|:z \in M^{\perp}, ||z||=1\}.$$

There isn't a lot of choice as to what one can do. I tried decomposing either $x$ or $y$ (or both) as a sum of two orthogonal vectors, which is a corollary of the projection theorem, and then tried to somehow take norms/inner products in order to find a relation between the two sides of the equation but this hasn't led me very far. I am struggling with the intuition behind the right-hand side - somehow, I cannot visualize it even in two dimensions. What am I missing? Thanks.

JJ

Comment: Try visualizing it in three dimensions, $M$ being a line. Then $\{z\in M^\perp,\; \lVert z\rVert = 1\}$ is a circle, that's a bit more instructive than the two-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_1\in M$ and $x_2\in M^\perp$, then the minimum on left hand side is attained at $y=x_1$, and the maximum on the right hand side is attained at $z=x_2/\lVert x_2\rVert$.